# Benchmarking Spark without using actions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to benchmark Spark's performance compared to Hive by running a simple query against a hive table, for example:

`spark.sql("select * from schema.table where col = 0")`

The problem is that due to Spark's lazy evaluation behavior, I must add an action to make it run.
I thought about using `.count()` to force the code to run, but I'm afraid it will change the way the application runs and make the comparison to Hive wrong, as each task will not only do filtering but will count as well.
Using `.show()` doesn't help either as it limits the results.
I also tried to look in the application Web UI and try to separate between the filtering and the counting to figure out how much time each of them took, but it seems to be combined into one task.

Ultimately, I want to force Spark to run my code without using an action but from what I understand it is impossible.
I'd like to hear if there's a way to solve this problem and in general what are the best ways to benchmark Spark in such cases (which actions can be used that affect Spark's performance the least, etc..)

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to compare hive against spark, why don't you use spark-sql.

Answer (score 1):

How about specifying the number of result data to a considerable number and then compare it in both Spark and Hive. I am not sure if it would justify your query but just a thought.

```
spark.sql("select * from schema.table where col = 0").show(10000)
```

You can provide the number of rows you want in the output and the same query appending with 'limit' can be used in hive to perform the benchmarking.

```
hive > select * from schema.table where col = 0 limit 10000;
```

Comment: That might be what I will do eventually. Although I think that the most accurate way to benchmark is to query the entire table because I don't know how 'limit' behaves exactly and if it works differently in Hive and Spark so I'm afraid it won't show the most accurate results. Thanks for your answer!